# Get user id from facebook with Laravel 5 Socialite

Tags: php, facebook, laravel-5

New guy here, I'm trying to get a facebook user id so I can display a link to their profile on my site, however with laravel socialite I get some id that is not the profile id, I don't realy know what it is, here is my setup, pretty basic stuff

```
public function getFbredirect() {
    return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
}

public function getFbredirectback() {
    $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();

    Session::set('fbid', $user); // stands for fb identity

    return redirect(Session::has('backto') ? Session::get('backto') : '/');
}
```

Then when I `dd(Session::get('fbid')` I get this object

[image]

As you can see there is an id but it is not the id I expect, the profile id I expect starts with `1`, the one I get starts with `9`.

So the question is how can I get the user's profile id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the correct ID, but it´s an "App Scoped ID" since v2.0 of the Graph API. You can´t use the global/real ID anymore, but you don´t need it anyway. Here´s more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids

Linking to the user profile works exactly the same way: `https://www.facebook.com/[app-scoped-id]`

Comment: That is unfortunate. I don't understand how to link to the user's profile using this scoped id?

Comment: just like you did it with the global id, there´s no difference. i´ve added an example.

Comment: If I go to `facebook.com/profile.php?id={scoped_id}` I don't get anything, so it is not the same?

Comment: see my example in the answer, that´s the profile link.

Comment: Yes, i saw it, it is incredible how much time I needed to spend to find this out. But wouldn't that mean that scoped IDs need to be unique as well throughout all apps? The amount of IDs will go through the roof, I must be missing something?

Comment: each user gets one unique app scoped id per app, so one user profile can be reachable through an unlimited amount of ids, for course.